# What are "must read"/classical refences on data aggregation/disaggregation in statistics?

Tags: statistics

I am looking for "must read"/classical references on data aggregation/disaggregation in statistics, particularly,  what they are exactly, why they are done and how statistical measures (media, mean, correlation coefficient, etc.) and  indexes (Human Development Index, poverty, gini, etc.) behave under agregation/disagregation of data.

Comment: you might do better on https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MatthewTowers, thanks!